# Preventing tooltip display for hyperlinks in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tooltip

Does anybody know how to get rid of the annoying tooltips that pop up in the bottom left of IE when you hover over a hyperlink?

[image: An example of the tooltip IE renders at the bottom left of the screen and I would like to control]

Alternatively, is there a way to set my own text against said hyperlink instead (I have tried setting the Title attribut but this shows up as well as the default rather than instead of).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status line display (it’s not a tooltip, and it’s not a popup) is a browser feature and cannot be disabled by code on your page. It is there for a reason: it lets the user see the destination of a link, which helps to prevent some types of fraud.

Some early browsers allowed authors to put their text on the status line, but this feature was regarded as too risky and has generally been removed.

Comment: I feared that this might be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the alt tag as well or better use a js solution for a better tooltip. That should change the tooltip

```
 <a href="#" alt="title" >Link</a>
```

You cannot change the status bar text anymore. In older browsers you could use window.status="" but it is not supported in any browsers anymore

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp

Comment: That would be quite a price to pay for the effect, considering e.g. what search engines think of pseudo-links.

Comment: I have tried using both Title and Alt; both of these affect the tooltip that is rendered next to the link that the cursor is hovering, but neither of them affect the URL tooltip displayed at the bottom left of the screen in IE. Thanks though.

Comment: that's not the tooltip. Its the status bar text. It can't be changed